# WooCommerce Always redirect to checkout even if product already exists in cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How can I always redirect to WooCommerce checkout even if the product sold **individually** is already in cart?

I have my cart integrated in the checkout and WooCommerce will stay on the same page without going to checkout if that product is already in the cart.

Best, Marian Alexandru Alecu

P.S.

- I followed [this](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-redirect-checkout-add-cart/) to redirect to checkout when adding to cart (no need for cart page cause I have only one product)
- And [this](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-cart-checkout-same-page/) to show the cart on checkout

Answer (score 2):

My fix was to hijack the add to cart flow of WooCommerce and redirect to checkout if the product already exists:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_sold_individually_found_in_cart', 'bypass_add_to_cart_sold_individually_found_in_cart', 10, 2 );

function bypass_add_to_cart_sold_individually_found_in_cart( $found_in_cart, $product_id ) {
    if ( $found_in_cart ) {
        wp_redirect(wc_get_checkout_url());
        
        exit;
    }
    
    return $found_in_cart;
}
```

Comment: You should mark your answer as accepted: (To mark an answer as accepted,
 click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in), thank you.